# SSL reissued but still having NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using SSL Let's Encrypt. It is revoked 2 days ago. I've generated a new Lets Encrypt SSL. When I do a cURL, the page returns successfully. When I access the website via browsers, it returns a NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED error. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Different builds of curl use different stacks, which differ in how and even if they check revocation, so curl's success doesn't really mean anything. If this server is public (as LE users are _supposed_ to be) try https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest . If the server is still sending the revoked cert and not the replacement, either there's something wrong in the server or you didn't do the replacement correctly, and the fix depends on what the cause is and probably on what server you are using and how, but it's not programming or development and thus unsuitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks! Knowing that curl's success doesn't mean anything helps greatly!

Comment: *"I've generated a new "* - just generating does not magically replace the old ones. They need to be actually installed at all the servers (and maybe load balancers) which hat the old ones. And these servers might  also need to be restarted so that the configuration takes effect. No details are known about your specific setup here so no more focused help can be given.

Answer (score -2):

TLS and SSL are the same thing. To explain, TLS is a higher-level protocol of SSL that has more security. Anyways, the situation you are having is because the browser trusts your cert and is expecting it to be valid. You should get your new certificate installed in the browser and then change the config of your server with it.

```
OpenSSL s_client -connect [host]:443 -servername [host] -showcerts < /dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep 'Subject:'

#or 
curl --cacert /etc/letsencrypt/live/[YOUR HOST]/fullchain.pem https://[YOUR HOST]/file --insecure

curl --cacert /etc/letsencrypt/live/[YOUR HOST]/fullchain.pem https://[YOUR HOST]

#check to make sure that the content you are getting matches the one on the server. (file, text, etc.) if you do a curl command without specifying an output file or a URL with --insecure, it will give you a true curl result code, but your output will be altered. You need to be able to verfiy that what you get is what is on the server.
```

If you have nginx and letsencrypt installed, there is an add-on called certbot-nginx for easy cert generation for nginx servers. There are some more advanced options if you are interested in a Lets Encrypt backend for your custom web server such as Apache or Nginx for example.

You can even set up your websites so that they are automatically updated when certificates expire by editing crontab entries on your system which can help reduce human error as well!

Comment: *"You should get your new certificate installed in the browser"* - this is wrong. The question is about certificates issued by  a public CA. The browser will automatically trust these since it trusts the public CA.